# Why is this function holomorphic in $K(a,\rho)$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, holomorphic-functions

If $\phi:\partial K(a,\rho)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue-integrable function, why is

$$z\mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+\frac{z-a}{\rho}}{e^{i\theta}-\frac{z-a}{\rho}}\phi(a+e^{i\theta})d\theta$$

holomorphic in $K(a,\rho)$?

Comment: Can you not use the CR equations to prove holomorphic?

Comment: Is $K(a,\rho)$ the ball centered at $a$, with radius $\rho$? If so - there's no $\rho$ in your integral -  is $a = 0$, and $\rho = 1$?

Comment: @peterag My bad. You are correct. We can assume that a=0 and $\rho=1$.

Comment: @peterag I edited the post for clarity.

Comment: You probably should also have $\phi ( a + \rho e^{i\theta})$ - you're missing the $\rho$... [Actually, I think you might be better off instead just setting $a =0$ and $\rho=1$: easier to read, and the (form of the) answer will be the same.]

Comment: Expanding the fraction in the integral into a power series with respect to $(z-a)/\rho$ and interchanging the summation and the integral yields $f(z)$ as an explicit power series, which converges at least for $|z-a|<\rho$, qed.

Answer (score 2):

You combine Morera's theorem and Fubini's theorem. For simplicity I will assume $a=0$, $\rho=1$.

Step 1. Show that the function
$$z\mapsto f(z)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}\,\phi(e^{i\theta})\,d\theta$$
is continuous.

Step2. Given a piecewise $C^1$ closed curve $\gamma$ contained in $K(0,1)$, then
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=\int_\gamma\Bigl(\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}\,\phi(e^{i\theta})\,d\theta\Bigr)\,dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Bigl(\int_\gamma\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}\,\phi(e^{i\theta})\,dz\Bigr)\,d\theta=0.
$$
I have used Fubini's theorem to interchange the order of integration and Cauchy's theorem to conclude that the integral is equal to $0$.

Step 3. Apply Morera's theorem.

Comment: Dont you have to show that the integrand is holomorphic to use Cauchy's Theorem and conclude the last equality? Also any straight forward ways to show the continuity?

Comment: @JulianAguirre - typo? you meant "closed curve."

Comment: @peterag Yes of course. Thank you for noticing.